Using Xamarin.Google.UserMessagingPlatform with MAUI for presenting a GDPR consent message
I am trying to present a GDPR consent message in a MAUI app using the Xamarin.Google.UserMessagingPlatform NuGet package.
I'm targeting Android 34 on .NET 8.
I have used both this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71299843/7360423 and this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69398471/7360423 suggested implementations, but nothing shows up. I get no errors, but also I don't get the expected consent message.
Has anyone succeeded presenting the GDPR consent with MAUI? Is a different approach needed?
